# Late email reception in Gmail

Tags: gmail

I am using multiple accounts in Gmail (including external ones) and have noticed since about 3 months the following issue: some emails that I receive on my uni email account show up in my inbox a couple weeks up to a couple of months late.

The concerned emails seem to exclusively come from LinkedIn and other mass-emailing platforms (not really an issue), but also from some coworkers that send me messages manually (can be a big deal). Any idea where this might come from?

Answer (score 1):

It's almost certainly upstream from Gmail.

We're all used to email showing up almost instantly in our mailboxes, but that's not how SMTP is designed to work. Messages can take any number of routes between the sending server and the receiving server. Sometimes they can get stuck. Maybe they end up on a server and suddenly it can't send them. Future messages will probably route around, but the messages in transit wait for the ability to move on.

The mysteries of SMTP are beyond the ken of this site, however. I can say that it's almost certainly nothing to do with Gmail. If you inspect the headers of these messages you should see where they were "hung up". Then again, the visible headers of email messages are ridiculously easy to spoof. I could easily send you a message today which would have a sent date of several weeks ago. You'd think it took weeks to get to you, when it took mere moments. (Along those lines, the date of LinkedIn's mail server may have been wonky for a while.)

Unfortunately, I don't know that there's anything you can do about it, except don't rely on email for time-sensitive communication.

Comment: I just checked the header of the message, and you are right it was held up in my university email server, fetching the email didn't work somehow.